# Can anyone explain why am i getting 'wrong answer'?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the 'Copy-Paste' programming problem (https://www.codechef.com/problems/RRCOPY ) of codechef
Here is what I have tried

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


bool isNumberInArray(int array[], int A, int size)

{
bool isFound = false;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == A)
    {
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

return isFound;

}


int main()

{
int T, i = 0, A, size = 0, count;
int array[100000];
cin >> T;
while(T--)
{
    cin >> size;
    count = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(size--)
    {
        cin >> A;
        if(isNumberInArray(array, A, count) == false)
        {
            array[i] = A;
            count++;
        }
        i++;        
    }   
    cout << count << endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong answer @ManKeer

Comment: We cannot guess what is wrong with some code. In general that takes too much time. You have to provide input, expected output, and actual output. If they are not available, then we most likely cannot help you.

Comment: All you're doing is adding elements to an array if they're not already in there. What does that have to do with the Copy-Paste problem.

Comment: I don't see how what you have written has anything to do with copy-paste algorithm. You are just filling your array several times and not even in consecutive places. You are adding `i` and not filling if the element is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes in your program.

First: Why is the variable `i` outside the if block. You are incrementing the index even if there are duplicates in your array. (You can just use `count` instead of i).

```
array[count]=A;
count++;
```

Second: You shouldn't print the result immediately after evaluating a testcase. You need to store all the results of all testcases in an array, and print them after you solve all of them.

Third: Your algorithm runs on O(n^2) which will definitely result in a TLE.

You need to improve your algorithm to O(n). My solution:https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/9011078

Next time please be more concise about what you want to ask.

Comment: What is the problem with outputting the result immediately?

Comment: I am not very sure about it... but when i wrote my solution in codechef and output the solutions immediately my solution got rejected, so I modified it and it got passed.

Comment: I solved some other problems in codechef, where I have printed the result immediately and it was accepted. @ParagAgarwal

Comment: Then maybe I am wrong. So your program has 2 mistakes.

Comment: Thank you @ParagAgarwal, for pointing out the mistakes in my code. Can you tell me what approach should follow when solving a programming problem.